# C# AutoMapper with a child of itself

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Can you AutoMap on objects with children of themselves?
In this example:

```
public class Book
{
    public int? BookKey { get; set; }
    public Categories bookCategories { get; set; }
}
public class Categories
{
    public int? CategoryKey { get; set; }
    public List<Book> RecommendedBooks { get; set; }
}


Mapper.CreateMap<Common.BookList, Book>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

Mapper.CreateMap<Common.Categories, Categories>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Swapping the last two maps around causes errors each time. Book first, means it doesn't understand categories, and categories first means it doesn't understand books.

AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: The following property on Common.BookList / Common.Categories cannot be mapped.

Comment: Remove the first `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`. You only need to call it once, once you've set up all your mapping rules. You're asking it to build the map for `Book`, but haven't told it how to do the `bookCategories` mapping yet.

Comment: How does COmmon.BookList look like? As I can see you are trying to map Booklist to Book. 

First you need to create a map for Book than one for Categories. Then you can map Book because you already have their mappings.

Comment: Rob's answer was exactly what I needed! I've always presumed I needed to call the AssertConfigurationIsValid after each one! Post again as an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: @RichardWhitehouse Great! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call the configuration validation *once*. It might make sense to have it multiple times to make debugging easier (which gives you an exception closer to the location of the mapping code), but in this case, the maps are dependent on each other (Building a map of `Book` requires Automapper to know how to map `bookCategories`).

Change the code to the below, and it will work fine

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Common.BookList, Book>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
Mapper.CreateMap<Common.Categories, Categories>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```